# GIT uploaded files to server

Tags: git, github

I am using git for the first time and even reading the documentation I am not able to find an answer to the following question.

What happens to the files that users upload in to the server when I push my project remotely? Do they get deleted?

Comment: Which files? What users? Which server?

Comment: The files that users upload to the server. Let me give you an example for further clarification:

User upload a picture for his blog into the server, what is going to happen to this picture if I do a push origin master?

Comment: Your question fundamentally doesn't make sense. GitHub stores the source code, it's not (except for static user.github.io sites) where the site would actually be  hosted. As to whether your users lose data when you deploy the new version of the site, that's nothing to do with GitHub and unanswerable without more information about where and how that data gets stored.

Comment: Ok, thank you jonrsharpe!